# Escape character required for batch query string

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I have below apex batch query string which fails to execute for which seems to be an issue with escape character required. Can someone help me here?

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    Date d = Date.today();
    String soql = 'SELECT Id, Name, Publish_Date_abv__c FROM Compliance_Incident_abv__c' +
        ' WHERE Publish_Date_abv__c+14 =: d';
    // above line fails to execute
    return Database.getQueryLocator(soql);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using invalid `SOQL`, `Publish_Date_abv__c+14` is not a valid field. Instead, modify the `Date` value you are comparing against.

```
Date twoWeeksAgo = Date.today().addDays(-14);
```

Then just compare against the above value in your string:

```
WHERE Publish_Date_abv__c = :twoWeeksAgo
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the +14, change d to be the data - 14 when populating the value for d

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    Date d = Date.today().addDays(-14);
    String soql = 'SELECT Id, Name, Publish_Date_abv__c FROM Compliance_Incident_abv__c WHERE Publish_Date_abv__c =: d';
    // above line fails to execute
    return Database.getQueryLocator(soql);
}
```